# Вычитание чисел от 1 до 100

Tags: python, случайные-числа

Задание: сделать тренажер вычитания от 1 до 100. Я его сделал, но надо сделать так, чтобы A всегда было больше B, чтобы у вас не было ответов отрицательных.

```
import math
from random import randint

print("я проверю навык вычитания чисел от 1 до 100")

a = randint(1, 100)
b = randint(1, 100)
while :
otvet = 0
plu = a-b
print(str(a) + str(" - ") + str(b) + str(" = ?"))
otvet = int(input("Введите правильный ответ = "))

while plu != otvet:
    if plu == otvet:
        print("Молодец это правильный ответ") 
        break
    otvet = int(input("Ой ошибся подумай еще раз, введите правильный ответ = "))
else:
    print("Молодец это правильный ответ")
```

Comment: Можно попробовать создать условие. Если a>b - выполняется программа, если нет - числа генерируются заново

Comment: Зачем? Если можно b сделать максимальное до сгенерированного a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import math
from random import randint


print("Я проверю навык вычитания чисел от 1 до 100.")

while True:
    a = randint(1, 100)
    b = randint(1, a)

    plu = a-b
    print(str(a) + str(" - ") + str(b) + str(" = ?"))
    otvet = int(input("Введите правильный ответ = "))

    while plu != otvet:
        if plu == otvet:
            print("Молодец, это правильный ответ.")
            break
        otvet = int(input("Ой, ошибся подумай еще раз, введите правильный ответ = "))
    else:
        print("Молодец, это правильный ответ.")
```